# AWS Email Service sending only encoded string

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I am trying to send the file attachment as pdf . It is working on almost everyphone but some phone showing wired behavior, Some phones are sending only BASE64 string in the email but not the pdf.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html
i am using this method to send email

Please let me know how i can solve this

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be the email client on the phones showing weird behaviour is broken.

Comment: @Henry how i can solve this

Comment: Good question, how can we get rid of all the lousy software in the world. I don't know the answer.

Comment: @Henry, that's pretty funny, but consider the possibility that the *broken* implementations may be the ones that are currently *showing* a PDF, because they are interpreting malformed content too loosely and as such are being unhelpfully "helpful" by masking a problem.  Wouldn't you say that the solution may involve examining the sending code as well as the rendered MIME structures?

Comment: @AmitSharma some phones are *sending* or some phones are *displaying?*  Where is the content sent from?